# JSON parsing an array from PHP filled with SQL data returns [object Object]

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to make a `PHP` file retrieve data from a `SQL DB` with an `Ajax` call, and store data in `JSON` format.

`Ajax` call

```
$.ajax({
    method:"POST",  
    dataType:"json",
    crossDomain:true,
    url:"getCourses.php", 
    success: function(response){

        var courses=JSON.parse(response);

        var el="";
        for(var i=0;i<courses.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(courses[i].title);
        }

    },
    error: function(request,error){
        console.log("ERROR: Request " + request + "\nSpecific Error: " + error);
    }
});
```

`PHP` function

```
 //this is a test, not the actual SQL query
$query="SELECT * FROM courses ORDER BY id;";
$result=$mysqli->query($query); 
if($result->num_rows >0) //if there is at least one row...
{
    $myArray= array(); //...create an array...
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){ //...fetch it...

        $myArray[]=$row; //...and add its row to $myArray ([] means autoincrement).
    }


    echo json_encode($myArray);
```

However, the Chrome console just gives me a `parserror`. I've been bashing my head since yesterday, and I can't seem to find the problem. I know that JSON has trouble with `non-UTF8` strings, but even doing a `utf8_encode` just gives this error.

**UPDATED**

I've only removed the JSON.parse method as told, and substituted it with

```
var courses=response;
```

In the PHP file instead, I've added the `headers` and this

```
foreach ($myArray as $row)
    {
        //UTF8 encoding to avoid parsing problems
        htmlentities($row['title'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"); 
        htmlentities($row['description'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");

    }
```

before the JSON encode. The Chrome console always returns me this

```
ERROR: Request [object Object]
Specific Error: parsererror
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not parse the json manually:

```
var courses=JSON.parse(response);
```

As you have specified the `dataType` as json, jQuery will parse it already, so `response` is already an object.

So you just need:

```
success: function(courses){
    var el="";
    for(var i=0;i<courses.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(courses[i].title);
    }
 },
```

Note that you always need to output valid json when you specify the `dataType` like that, so if you `if` condition in the php script is not met, you should send your error message as json as well.

Comment: Worth sending the valid mime type too `header('Content-type: application/json');` just before your `echo json_encode($myArray);`

Comment: @KevinNagurski Possibly, but I have never had to use it on the servers I work with.

Comment: not required, but helps the browser and means you can do a manual GET request and have the browser parse the result as JSON rather than display as flat text (very browser dependant) Good answer thought (upvoted :-)

Comment: It won't work. It returns the same `parseerror`. I'm using  `xampp` for an Apache test server, maybe I have to edit something in the settings...?

Comment: @RiccardoLomazzi Can you post your updated code under the original code? You should also do a `console.log(courses);` and post the output.

Comment: Okay, I've managed to resolve the error, it was a utf8_encoding problem. Still, this post remains the best solution, because I need to manipulate the object, and you also explained what does datatype do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should send the **correct headers** and save your php file into "**UTF-8 without BOM**" format.

```
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
 header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
 header('Content-type: application/json');
```

If you still have troubles, you can use this library : [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) that helps to forge easily a JSON in

Comment: Add `console.log(request)` under `console.log("ERROR: Request " + request + "\nSpecific Error: " + error);`

Comment: With this you will be able to see the complete error in the console